# How do I run a C program that involves an external library in a PHP script?

Tags: php, c, exec

I created a simple C program that takes an integer argument and outputs that integer plus two. I can run it in a terminal with

`./simplep 2`

and in PHP with

`exec('./simplep 2', $output)`.

I have a more complicated program called `myprogram` which involves an external library. I can run it in the terminal with

`./myprogram a.mov`

but it fails if I run it in PHP with

`exec('./myprogram a.mov', $output)`

No output is produced, which makes me think the program isn't running at all.

PS. I am working on Mac.

**update**

From the error ouput I know the problem is the library. It says

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib".
```

But the library file is there.

Comment: What does the error message say?  If there is no error message, make sure PHP error reporting is enabled.  If there still isn't any error message then it sounds like your program is failing... is it reporting errors correctly?

Comment: What OS is this?  I assumed a UNIX operating system because of the forward slashes.

Comment: Windows can stop gui apps from opening, see comment at bottom: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Comment: @cdhowie I enabled the error reporting, and there is no error reported.

Comment: @notfed It says "cannot execute binary file". I tried `chmod +x` but still get this error.

Comment: @xuc: Try `exec('./myprogram a.mov 2>err.out', $output)` and look at `err.out`. If it really needed `chmod +x` you'd get `Permission denied`.

Comment: @notfed Okay. Now I know it is the problem with the external library.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably producing an error, but it's going to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  One simple way to view `stderr` here is to change:

```
exec('./myprogram a.mov', $output)
```

to

```
exec('./myprogram a.mov 2>err.out', $output)
```

and view the file `err.out` to see what the error message is.

EDIT:

Now that you posted the error, it looks like a dynamic library is not being loaded. The most likely reason is that environment variables are not being passed to `exec`, and the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is being cleared out.   See what `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is on your terminal (via `env`), then try running:

```
exec('env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=XYZ ./myprogram a.mov 2>err.out', $output)
```

Where XYZ is the value of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have right permissions to run myprogram with exec? Try this

```
chmod +x myprogram
```

Comment: That's odd. Can you see if there are any logs doing **cd /var/log; grep -R -n myprogram ./***

Answer (score 0):

If your program runs on command line, try using shell_exec instead of exec.